# How to block users signup for given IDP in B2C Custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I've created a custom policy that use two IDP, I'd like to permit that users can SignUp only from one IDP and allow Sign In from both IDP.

Starting from the SocialAccounts of [MS starter pack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/SocialAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml) I'm trying to modify the SignUpOrSignIn UserJourney.

OrchestrationStep 4 and 5 create new user if the objectId isn't present.

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
   <Preconditions>
     <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
       <Value>objectId</Value>
       <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
     </Precondition>
   </Preconditions>
   <ClaimsExchanges>
     <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Social" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Social" />
   </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>

<OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
   <Preconditions>
      <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
        <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
     </Precondition>
   </Preconditions>
   <ClaimsExchanges>
     <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWrite" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
   </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

For exclude registration for user coming from one specifc IDP I've added this Precondition on both step

```
      <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
        <Value>identityProvider</Value>
        <Value>https://myIdpdprovider</Value>
        <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
      </Precondition>
```

Is this the right solution for my intent?

Comment: if you want to block all users from registering with provider https://myIdpdprovider, then this pre-condition will work.

Comment: Thank you, I've tested and as you tell it works. But I wonder if this is the right solution or it is just a work around

Comment: I think so, this is the simplest way I can think of.

Comment: B2C lets you do things the way you want, there is not really a "right" way here, you can use whatever logic to achieve the result you want. If you tested it, and it works, then it works. The idea here is what comes to my mind in first instance also :)

Comment: Hello @Luca, If my answer is helpful for you, you can Upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank You  [Jas Suri - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8357357/jas-suri-msft) and Alex for providing your suggestion. Posting your suggestion as an answer to help others community member.

> Custom policies are configuration files that define the behaviour of
> your Azure Active Directory B2C (Azure AD B2C) tenant. While [user
> flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-overview)
> are predefined in the Azure AD B2C portal for the most common identity
> tasks, A custom policy is represented as one or more XML-formatted
> files. custom policies can be fully edited by an identity developer to
> complete many different tasks

For Excluding the registration of users for the specific IDP i.e. already in custom policy fixes with added the IDP in the precondition section and applied the action on it.